# Various ways to set up proxy?

Tags: networking, gnome, ssh, proxy

I am using gnome-classic on Ubuntu 14.04. I am confused about different ways that can set up proxies.

1. In gnome-classic's Settings->Network->Network Proxy,

   (1) When the method is Manual, (See screen shot below)

   - will the settings of HTTP proxy, HTTPS Proxy, and FTP proxy   affect all and only the programs that use HTTP, HTTPS, and FTP
     respectively?
   - will the setting of SOCKS proxy with a port  affect all and only those programs attached to the port?

   (2) when the method is Automatic, it says "Web Proxy AutoDiscover is
   used when a configurtion URL is not provided" (see screen shot below). But I check that
   there is no proxy. Do I miss something?
2. In a program, such as Firefox or ssh client, if I set up a proxy in its settings,
   will the proxy   only affect the program, not any other programs?
3. In the way of environment variables, what programs are affected by
   the values of `HTTP_PROXY`, `FTP_PROXY`, and `SOCKS_SERVER`?
4. What are differences and relation between the above three way? For example, are the gnome network settings for proxy essentially the same as those settings in proxy environment variables?

   How do the proxy settings in the three ways (in a program, in  Gnome network settings,
   and in environment variables) work together?

   - Does some setting override another setting?
   - are the proxy settings   all used,  in the way that the proxy servers are used in a chain (i.e. the program first uses the proxy
     server in gnome network setting, which in turn uses the proxy server
     in the environment variables, which in turn uses the proxy server in
     the program)  ?
   - are the proxy settings all used, in the way that for a program to use a proxy server, the proxy server must be set up in gnome network
     settings, in the program's own settings, and/or in an environment
     variable? For example, do I need to set up a proxy server in my
     browser after set up the proxy server as HTTP proxy in gnome network
     settings?

Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have a lot of questions, too many IMO for this format. Yes, a proxy is set per protocol (http, https, ftp most common) and once set affects all applications / programs using that protocol. There can be some exceptions, such as apt. See https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Proxy_settings

Answer (score 1):

1. If you set this up system-wide, the application that respect system-wide setup (do not have manual override or ignore this settings) will be affected.

   a) Yes, as proposed in the comment. But the SOCKS proxy is quite different, since it should direct all the traffic through that port.

   b) Did you fill the configuration URL?
2. Yes. If you set up manual proxy for and in Firefox, only Firefox will be affected.

Answering only parts I know. Others are left for another answerers.

Comment: Thanks. About 1 (2) I didn't. But it says "Web Proxy AutoDiscover is used when a configurtion URL is not provided". I don't know what is "Web Proxy AutoDiscover", but isn't this thing supposed to do the job when I didn't provide a configuration URL? By the way what is "a configuration URL" used for?

Comment: Yes. You are right. I read wrong for the first time. I have no idea how does it work, but I guess there is some protocol that can be used in corporate networks (for example on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol)). Nothing for us mortal :)